# How to block until a condition is met

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to know what the best way is to block a method until a condition becomes true.

Example:

```
class DoWork
{
  int projects_completed;
  public:
  .....
  void WaitForProjectsCompleted()
  {
   ---->//How do I block until projects_completed == 12;
  }
};
```

I want it to be used as such

```
class foo
{
 ....
 void someMethod()
 {
    DoWork work;
    work.WaitForProjectsCompleted();//This should block
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "block"?, are you working with multi tasking? do you want to exit function/method?

Comment: YEs the DoWork class employs mutiple threads that increment an atomic member variable. I would like the someMethod() to not return until the atomic variable has a specific value say 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that there's another thread that's actually going to do something here, an easy thing to use is a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable):

```
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;

void WaitForProjectsCompleted() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    cv.wait(lk, [this]{ 
       return projects_completed >= 12; 
    });
}
```

Where somewhere else, some other member function might do:

```
void CompleteProject() {
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
        ++projects_completed;
    }
    cv.notify_one(); // let the waiter know
}
```

---

If `projects_completed` is atomic, you could instead just spin:

```
void WaitForProjectsCompleted() {
    while (projects_completed < 12) ;
}
```

That would work fine too.

Comment: Is there something about `std::atomic` that I'm not getting that makes the spin solution not terrible?

Comment: Good answer until the atomic busy-wait suggestion, which should at least come with an explanation of the potential problems....

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Why terrible?

Comment: @Barry: Spinning like that is a terrible idea unless the condition is guaranteed to occur rapidly; otherwise, you're eating a core of the computer (and foiling all power conservation the chip/OS might otherwise use, a big problem for battery powered phones/tablets/laptops) constantly checking something that won't change for a while.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Sometimes eating a core is a perfectly acceptable trade-off for the latency gain. Blanketly saying it's terrible is silly.

Comment: @Barry: When it's a bad idea in the vast majority of cases, introducing the concept without the caveats leads to terrible, battery draining code releasing into the wild. 99% of the time, explicitly spin looping is a bad idea (most exceptions are in OS kernels, and that's not the common case most programmers need to handle). And as it happens, some (many?) lock implementations actually incorporate a short spin loop to try to grab low hanging fruit anyway (I believe Win32's Conditions do this) or use adaptive mutexes (that spin if the lock owner is currently running, and block if its not).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Throwing out color descriptions like "vast majority of cases" or "99% of the time" doesn't make it a better argument. Clearly, 99% of C++ code isn't even running on battery-powered devices.

Comment: @Barry: Sigh, you really want to argue the point? Spinlocks, on top of wasting battery, have fairness issues (starving threads accidentally/arbitrarily; fixable, but it means the lock is a lot less lightweight, not just a simple loop), deny CPU to other processes/threads (you're rarely the only one on the system), increased bus traffic (varies by CPU), etc. There is a reason blocking locks exist; spin locks are for special cases, not the common case, thus the need for caveats when mentioning them. Oh, and w/o explicit memory ordering, that busy loop is probably invoking full memory barriers.

Answer (score 1):

Condition variables are an excellent synchronization primitive, and in my personal experience it is the tool I respond with to 95% of synchs/threading situations.

If you don't have C++11 available you can use `boost::condition_variable`.
In which case you won't have the `wait` version with a predicate (because no lambdas in C++03). So you absolutely need to remember to loop over your condition check. As explained in the docs:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mut);
while (projects_completed < 12)
{
    wait(lock);
}
```

c.f.:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref

That's because you get no guarantee that the condition is fulfilled after a notification, particularly because the lock can be acquired by another thread in the interstice between unlock and notify. Also a spurious wake up could happen.

I also wrote an article about it:
http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/multithreading-r3048

Also if you use `timed_wait` (and I recommend it as it often mitigates [priority inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion)), another trap not to fall into is the timeout, because of the loop you cannot use a relative timeout (like 2 seconds) you need an absolute system time determined before entering the loop.
`boost` makes it very clean with this technique:

```
system_time const timeout = get_system_time() + posix_time::seconds(2);
```

About the spin lock pattern proposed by Barry, I would not recommend it, unless you are in a real time environment, like playstation 3/4 or equivalent. Or unless you are sure it won't last for more than a few seconds.
By using spin locking you waste power, and you don't leave chance for CPU to enter sleep states (c.f intel speed step).
This also has consequences on fairness and scheduling, as explained on wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock

Finally if you don't have boost, since windows Vista we get natives Win32 functions:
`SleepConditionVariableCS`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686301(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I just want to point out that functions taking predicates totally were a thing in C++03 (you just needed to define the predicate externally), so there's no reason Boost couldn't've included that wait function. IOW, if Boost _didn't_ include it, it's not due to any missing language support.

Comment: true story. and further indeed, boost lambda existed in C++03 (limited to expressions using operator overloading), even though compiler support was horrible.

Comment: True, I remember looking at Boost.Lambda, though I never actually used it.